# Grid System dont working with bootstrap tabs

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Im working on a tabs area. Im using row system via container. But the rows are doesnt work with the tabs. I find the problem in css file. But i cant solve it.

[i want to use this selected area

```html
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                                <div class="tab-pane fade show active row " id="kt_vtab_pane_2" role="tabpanel">

                                <div class="container" >
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <span><b>Raporlanma Zamanı:</b> 10.11.2021 15:23</span><br>
                                        <span><b>Açıklama:</b> <a href="#">Havlu İsteniyor</a> </span><br>
                                        <span><b>Konum:</b> <a href="#">1453</a> </span>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <span><b>Çözüm:</b> 10 Dakika</span><br>
                                        <span><b>Atanan Yetkili:</b> <a href="#">Yağız Savaş</a> </span><br>
                                        <span><b>Görevli:</b> <a href="#">HK Runner</a> </span><br>
                                        <span><b>Görevli Departman:</b> <a href="#">Hause Keeping</a> </span><br>
                                        <span><b>Geri Arama:</b>Gerekmiyor</span><br>
                                        <span><b>Öncelik Seviyesi:</b>2</span>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>

                            </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane fade " id="kt_vtab_pane_3" role="tabpanel">lorem</div>
                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="kt_vtab_pane_4" role="tabpanel">lorem</div>
                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="kt_vtab_pane_5" role="tabpanel">lorem</div>
                            </div>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w11vn.png)

The problem class is tab-content and tab-pane. This style codes are here ; `.tab-content>.tab-pane {
display: none;
}

.tab-content>.active {
display: block;
`

please help me i dont now what will i do :/

Answer (score 0):

The route of your problem and problems to come is having containers and rows structured incorrectly. Ideally and for proper Bootstrap  your structure should be.

```
<section>
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-12">
          <!-- Your tabs here -->
```

You should not have containers and rows inside other elements. You should put your tabs and related elements inside a column. All columns are inside a row. All rows are inside containers.

Comment: Thanks but i try it, its un work like this

Comment: i did it like that but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="kt_vtab_pane_2" role="tabpanel">
    <div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <span><b>Raporlanma Zamanı:</b> 10.11.2021 15:23</span><br>
            <span><b>Açıklama:</b> <a href="#">Havlu İsteniyor</a> </span><br>
            <span><b>Konum:</b> <a href="#">1453</a> </span>

        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <span><b>Çözüm:</b> 10 Dakika</span><br>
            <span><b>Atanan Yetkili:</b> <a href="#">Yağız Savaş</a> </span><br>
            <span><b>Görevli:</b> <a href="#">HK Runner</a> </span><br>
            <span><b>Görevli Departman:</b> <a href="#">Hause Keeping</a> </span>             <br>
            <span><b>Geri Arama:</b>Gerekmiyor</span><br>
            <span><b>Öncelik Seviyesi:</b>2</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
    
  <div class="tab-pane fade " id="kt_vtab_pane_3" role="tabpanel">lorem</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="kt_vtab_pane_4" role="tabpanel">lorem</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="kt_vtab_pane_5" role="tabpanel">lorem</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but same results as me :(

Comment: Did you run my code?

@UretimAjansi which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: yes i run bro, last version im using